# Объясните, что такое разреженные матрицы, как их генерировать и математические операции над ними

Tags: c++, матрицы

Скажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я думаю.
На сколько я понял разреженная матрица - это матрица вроде этой:

```
1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0
1 0 0 1
```

Если это разреженная матрица - то генерировать ее элементы можно функцией `rand()` :
`rand()%2`

Идентичен ли этот вид матриц квадратным матрицам (ряды=столбцам)? Математические операции (+,-,*,/) проводятся так же?
Спасибо!

Comment: Разр**я**женная матрица - это которую давно не заряжали :), а разр**е**женная - это в которой ненулевых элементов очень немного по отношению к общему количеству, так что для экономии хранятся только они, а не все элементы матрицы...

Comment: Какие шаги Вы предприняли, чтобы выяснить это самостоятельно?

Comment: @Igor Я читал в Википедии, но сугубо про математическую точку зрения. Более ничего не смог найти. Поэтому и обратился на этот форум

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот представьте, что вам нужно работать с матрицами целых чисел размером 1000х1000. Легко подсчитать, что размер каждой матрицы будет 4Мб, а для перемножения двух матриц потребуется миллиард умножений и почти столько же сложений.

Если же мы знаем, что ненулевых элементов в матрице будет в районе 0.1%, то есть порядка 1000, то представление матрицы и работу с ней можно сильно оптимизировать. Например, можно представить матрицу как простой массив ненулевых элементов, где каждый ненулевой элемент представлен такой структурой:

```
typedef struct {
  short row;
  short column;
  int value;
} NonZeroElem;
```

Тогда матрица вместо миллиона четырехбайтовых целых будет представлена всего лишь тысячью восьмибайтовых описателей. То есть 8кб вместо 4Мб - в пятьсот раз меньше.

Операции с матрицами в таком представлении будут выглядеть гораздо сложнее, но за счет того, что операций будет минимум на три порядка меньше, скорость тоже сильно возрастет.

Разумеется, разреженные матрицы могут быть представлены и другим способом, который для конкретного вида матриц (числа нулей и их распределения) может оказаться выгоднее.